# Spring Security - 403 error occurs when CSRF is enabled and logout requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

As shown below, the document says that you can make a logout post request with the csrf token. If I got it right....
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/logout.html

> Aside from providing a valuable double-checking mechanism for the user, it also provides a simple way to provide the needed CSRF token to POST /logout.

But 403 errors occur when CSRF is enabled and logout request. And I was able to fix the error by specifying `csrf().ignoreAntMatchers({logout url})`.

As forementioned, the document said to provide csrf tokens, but why does it work without errors when I used `ignoreAntMatchers` it?

#### securityFilterChain

```java
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oAuth2UserService,
            CustomOAuth2SuccessHandler customOAuth2SuccessHandler
    ) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                        .mvcMatchers(
                                ...
                                "/account/logout"
                        ).permitAll()
                        .mvcMatchers(
                                "/account/login",
                                ...
                        ).hasRole("ANONYMOUS")
                        ...
                )
                .csrf()
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/account/logout")
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                ...
                .and()
                    .formLogin().disable()
                    .logout(logout -> logout
                            .logoutUrl("/account/logout")
                    )
                    .oauth2Login(oAuth -> oAuth
                            .loginPage("/account/login")
                            .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                                    .userService(oAuth2UserService))
                            .successHandler(customOAuth2SuccessHandler)
                    )
                    //i'm using jwt token
                    .addFilterBefore(
                            new JwtTokenFilter(userAccountService, jwtProperties),
                            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    ...
    }
```

#### Custom Logout Endpoint

```java
SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();

@PostMapping("/account/logout")
public String requestLogout(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.logoutHandler.logout(request, response, authentication);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

#### FrontEnd

```html
    <form id="logout" action="/account/logout" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn text-success p-0">LogOut</button>
    </form>
```

#### Error on chrome

trace error log did not appear. **server logs there's nothing.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because ignore means that the request is ignored from the security filter chain which means that the csrf filter is not invoked on that request. Why you are getting a 403 is for us impossible to tell since you have not provided what your raw request looks like or any debug or trace logs from the server.

Comment: @Toerktumlare trace error log did not appear. so, attached chrome capture image.

Comment: Please read my comment, the SERVERS logs, not the browser, not what is returned to browser. What the server writes to its log file or standard out.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I said there's nothing. I know what you want, but I don't

Comment: When you start your spring server it starts writing stuff to the console. Thats the log

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you for your effort to answer. However, this issue has been resolved and I have added the following answer.

Comment: and i hope you are aware of the fact that using a JWT like you have done is insecure, and that is why there is no such filter in spring security because they also know its insecure. JWTs where never meant to be sent to browsers. So start googling why jwt should not be used as sessions. If you intend to use jwts as a server to server token then read the "resource server" chapter in the spring docs. But to browser just dont if you want a vulnerable application. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue was the **Stateless session** setting. By default, Spring Security stores the expected CSRF token in the HttpSession by using `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository`. So, the CSRF token could not be loaded.

I was able to persist the CsrfToken in a cookie using the `CookieCsrfTokenRepository`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // ...
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-token-repository-cookie

In addition, after applying a stateless session, it was regenerated by the `CsrfAuthenticationStrategy`, resulting in a token mismatch error. This issue was solved by placing the `jwtFilter` before the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` or after the `SessionMnagmentationFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly mentioned, when using `.ignoringAntMatchers("/account/logout")` you are disabling CSRF protection for that endpoint. The reason behind the 403 response could be that the CSRF token is not part of the POST request.

There are different ways to do this, but a common approach is to have the token in a hidden input field within your form. For example, if you are working with JSP, an easy way to do it is to access and render the CSRF token with Expression Language, by using `${_csrf.parameterName}` and `${_csrf.token}`.

An example:

```
<form action="/logout" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Log out"/>
</form>
```

and Spring takes care of the rest. More info here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i didn't working with JSP. Spring Security automatically adds the CSRF input field into the form.